concatenating subcaptions without newlines or self-references
The subcaption package is helpful for automatic numbering of the panels of multi-panel figures.  However, it is non-standard, in many journals, to divide the panel-specific captions among separate parboxes/minipages, as subcaption is designed to do.  Instead, there is often an expectation that panel-specific captions be concatenated so as to form a continuous block of text.
This can be accomplished with the subcaption package, as shown in Figure 1 in the below MWE.  However, this approach has the drawback of requiring an explicit self-reference for each element of the subcaption.  Also, the subcaption labels and subcaption text are segregated in the source code; i.e., the source becomes, in pseudocode, something like \sublabel1 \sublabel2 \sublabel3 and then later \subref1\text1 \subref2\text2 \subref3\text3.  Instead, one might prefer to eliminate self-references and streamline the code so that it resembles the following pseudocode: \sublabel1\text1 \sublabel2\text2 \sublabel3\text3.  An attempt at this sort of syntax was made in Figure 2 of the MWE; however, it does not give the desired effect, as the panel-specific captions each begin on a new line.  Thinking this might be because the format for caption text ends with a \par by default, a new format lacking this was defined, but to no avail.
Can the aesthetic of Figure 1 be achieved with syntax resembling that of Figure 2?  A solution would ideally preserve access to subreferences (e.g., \subref{fig:1:a} -> "a"), both within the caption and beyond, as well as access to combined figure-panel references (e.g., \cref{fig:1:a} -> "fig. 1a").  Having perused the manuals for caption and subcaption, I was unable to identify a solution, though my understanding of these packages is admittedly far from complete.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%per `texdoc subcaption`, the default caption format is
%       \DeclareCaptionFormat{plain}{#1#2#3\par}
%thinking that removal of \par would avoid the newline at end of caption text:
\DeclareCaptionFormat{nopar}{#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=nopar}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        {
                \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:1:a}
                \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:1:b}
        }
        \caption{
                The desired aesthetic, but with more commands than desired.
                (\subref{fig:1:a}) A box.
                (\subref{fig:1:b}) Another box.
        }
        \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{The desired command structure but with undesired newlines between caption elements.}
        {
                \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:2:a}
                \subcaptiontext{A box.}
                \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:2:b}
                \subcaptiontext{Another box.}
        }
        \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



How about this layout?

@Werner: Thanks, but unfortunately it's not accepted by many journals.  That is the layout referenced by the remark about splitting the caption elements into separate parboxes/minipages.

So your main quest here is to avoid writing your section of \phantomsubcaptions? You could just write your own command that combines your \phantomsection/\label setup... making it less verbose.

do (a) and (b) refer to anything other than (1)? I mean do you need to cross-reference them?

@Werner: No, the \phantomsubcaption\label bit is common to both; it's more about avoiding the need for an explicit self-reference for each panel's sub-caption, a la \subref{...}.
@cfr: I'm not certain I understand your question, but more than one multi-panel figure can its own (a) and (b).  Within the caption for a given figure, it may be necessary for one panel to refer back to another panel (e.g., panel b might need to refer to something in panel a).  Outside a caption, one might need to do something like \cref{fig:3:a}--\subref{fig:3:c} to get "Fig. 3a-c".

@user001: How about this option?

@Werner: On initial glance, it looked superb.  However, on closer inspection I now see the label=... in the includegraphics.  Thus, it retains the problem of needing a separate label and self-reference.  Also, in some cases, one has prepared, outside of latex, a montage (of panels), and in those cases there would only be one call to \includegraphics.

@user001: Well, you don't need to reference them. You can just type (a), (b), ... and only use the label option for those that you want to reference elsewhere in the document.

@Werner: This is true, and it's what I did before adopting the solution used in Figure 1; however, in practice, it's often the case that one needs to refer to each panel and so having per-panel labels ends up being very helpful to avoid misreferencing as the composition of figures evolves.  I can certainly live with the syntax of Figure 1, and merely hoped there might be a simpler solution.

so can't you just have a macro e.g. \superlabel{<number of subfigures>}{<basename>} which generates <number of subfigures> refs and labels based on <basename> e.g. fig:<basename>, fig:<basename>:a, fig:<basename>:b etc.? you don't actually need them to be in different places. (actually, the whole setup is non-standard in that regard.) but, of course, the whole reason for using labels in the first place is because you don't want to hard code the a etc. but you have to if they are to be auto-generated. or you could have \superlabe{<figname>}{<subfigname>,<anothersubfigname>,...}.

Another way to achieve Figure 1 with fewer commands.  Note that \captionlist is defined locally inside the figure environment and will be empty again at the start of the next figure.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%per `texdoc subcaption`, the default caption format is
%       \DeclareCaptionFormat{plain}{#1#2#3\par}
%thinking that removal of \par would avoid the newline at end of caption text:
\DeclareCaptionFormat{nopar}{#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=nopar}

\newcommand{\captionlist}{}% global reset
\newcommand{\mysub}[2]{% #1=caption, #2=image
  \subfloat[]{#2}%
  \edef\captionlist{\captionlist\hskip1em(\thesubfigure)~#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \mysub{A box.}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfil
        \mysub{Another box.}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
        \caption{%
                The desired aesthetic, but with more commands than desired.
                \captionlist
        }
        \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


This version has an optional argument for a label name.  It also places the subcaption alongside the image to save vertical space.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%per `texdoc subcaption`, the default caption format is
%       \DeclareCaptionFormat{plain}{#1#2#3\par}
%thinking that removal of \par would avoid the newline at end of caption text:
\DeclareCaptionFormat{nopar}{#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=nopar}

\newcommand{\captionlist}{}% global reset
\newcommand{\mysub}[3][\empty]{% #1=label name (optional), #2=caption, #3=image
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{1.5em}
    \captionsetup{skip=0pt}%
    \caption{}%
    \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \else
      \label{#1}%
    \fi
  \end{subfigure}%
  \raisebox{-\height}{#3}%
  \edef\captionlist{\captionlist\hskip1em(\thesubfigure)~#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \mysub{A box.}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfil
        \mysub{Another box.}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
        \caption{%
                The desired aesthetic, but with more commands than desired.
                \captionlist
        }
        \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


That does give the desired aesthetic, but can one still make use of subreferences?

With \subfloat, you can either place the \label inside #2 or inside the optional argument.  \label uses information local to the subfigure.
